# Convective derivative of oscillating fluid with bulk motion?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, plasma-physics

I have a fluid $u$, which comprises a zeroth order constant motion $u_0$ as well as a first order oscillatory motion $u_1$.

The convective derivative is 
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} +u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$
where $u=u_0+u_1$

We are assuming a linear solution, so that second order terms (any products of 1st order terms) are neglected.

I know that the time derivative will be $\partial(u_1+ u_0)/\partial t$

but I have no idea how to linearized the flow part:
$$(u_0+u_1)·\frac{\partial(u_0+u_1)}{\partial x}$$

Because we are assuming linear solution, we can move into frequency domain, and above expression is:

$(u_0+u_1)·ik(u_0+u_1)$ - I'm afraid that I still don't get how to go about linearizing. My guess is FOILing it out and dropping $u_1u_1$ terms, but I want to be confident before moving forward.

Comment: Your thinking is on the right track, keep the terms containing u0 and u0*u1 but not the terms containing u1*u1.

Answer (score 2):

You said that $u_0$ is a constant piece. Do you mean constant in space, or time, or both?

In any case, the advection term $u \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ will be expanded out as $(u_0 + u_1) \cdot \frac{\partial (u_0 + u_1)}{\partial x}$. But assuming that your perturbation $u_1$ is small (if you like, think about hanging an $\varepsilon$ in front of the $u_1$ to explicitly show that it is small), you can drop terms of order $u_1^2$, keeping only terms of order $u_1$ (if you like $\varepsilon$, that's dropping terms of order $\varepsilon^2$ in comparison to terms of order $\varepsilon$).

Thus, you will have for the convective term (Note: here, I'm assuming that $u_0$ is not constant in space for generality):

$u_0 \cdot \nabla (u_0 + u_1) + u_1 \cdot \nabla u_0$

after neglecting the $u_1 \cdot \nabla u_1$ term which is of order $u_1^2$.

Now, the above term is linear in $u_1$, so you have linearized the advection term.